# Importing a local Python module fails

Tags: python, import, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a folder structure

```
src

├── lib
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── ...
├── tests
│   ├── foo.py
│   └── ...
```

with `foo.py` starting with

```py
from lib import Foo
```

If I call `python3 tests/foo.py` from `src` in ubuntu wsl, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../src/tests/foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from lib import Foo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'
```

This works if I move `foo.py` into `src`. How do I solve this?

Comment: If you did `cd src` / `python tests/foo.py`, that would work.  Perhaps you should `print(os.getcwd())` to make sure you are where you think you are.

Comment: `from os import getcwd` gives me that I'm in `src`. I think this is weird and maybe wsl-specific.

Comment: You've triple-checked that `__init__.py` exists?  Other than that, I have no explanation.  It works for me.

Comment: Yes, if I move `foo.py` into `src` the `lib` gets imported, so I think it's not a problem with the library.